# Problem with Region Intersection

Tags: warning-messages, regions

I have two regions defined as ImplicitRegion[].

```
R[1]=ImplicitRegion[-x[1] + x[2] > 0 && 
  x[3] > 0 && -x[1] > 0 && -2 x[1] + x[2] + x[3] < 1, {x[1], x[2], 
  x[3]}];
R[2]=ImplicitRegion[
 x[2] > 0 && -x[1] + x[3] > 0 && -x[1] > 0 && -2 x[1] + x[2] + x[3] < 
   1, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}];
```

Now, when I take `RegionIntersection[]` between them although Mathematica can calculate it correctly but it always shows the error "SymbolName::sym: Argument x[1] at position 1 is expected to be a symbol."

```
RegionIntersection[R[1],R[2];
```

How can I get rid of it? I know one method is to use `//Quiet`. But any better way to do it? Because I cannot change `x[1]` to `x1` due to other constraints.

Comment: Use of `Subscript[x,j]` does not help here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. No. It is showing a similar error "Argument Subscript[x, 1] at position 1 is expected to be a symbol".

Comment: Looks like a bug?

Comment: Maybe. Mathematica is not able to take x[1] or Subcript[x,1] as a symbol. Is it possible to forcefully convert them into a "symbol" so that the error does not arise?

Comment: To turn off just that specific type of error message without affecting others, use `Off[SymbolName::sym]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. But when I perform try to do Parallelization the error still arises. Any way to get rid of the error for all kernels?

Comment: I've never used parallelization but just looking at the documentation, have you tried `ParallelEvaluate[Off[SymbolName::sym]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks a lot. It worked!